# Combine MSBuild solution output to one folder

Tags: msbuild

What is the simplest way in MSBuild to override the output for all projects in a solution to go to a single folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to specify an absolute path for /p:OutputPath= because a relative path will go relative to each project file.

Answer (score 1):

Set $(OutDir) to gather output of all the projects in one location.