# Why would one compile all projects to one directory?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, build, compilation, msbuild

Extending [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8344861/combine-msbuild-solution-output-to-one-folder) questions,

I want to know, what is the reason, one would want to compile multiple projects to a **single directory?**

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There could be multiple reasons.

One that I think could be usual is for continuous integration and preparing deployment packages.

You want to have all your code in the same folder in order to be able to run your unit tests (so they find the assemblies you are testing), and also that can make easier to build a release package for your application.